# How to change the content of a tab while you are on the same tab using AngularJS and Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using AngularJS and Bootstrap, let say there are 3 tabs: tab1, tab2, and tab3. There are also some links on each tabs. Now for example, tab1 is active. The question is: how to change the content of the tab1 by clicking a link within the same tab?

```
main.html:
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'tab1'}"><a ng-click="activeTab = 'tab1'" href="">tab1</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'tab2'}"><a ng-click="activeTab = 'tab2'" href="">tab2</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'tab3'}"><a ng-click="activeTab = 'tab3'" href="">tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div ng-include="'/'+activeTab"></div>
</div>

tab1.html:
<h1>TAB1</h1>
<a href="/something">Something</a>

something.html
<h1>SOMETHING</h1>
```

Now the question is how to change the tab1 content to something.html while the tab1 is active?

Comment: There are very many ways of doing it. You should post a more concrete question to get a good answer (possibly with some code). Also, consider using [ui.bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap) instead of plain `bootstrap` for better angular integration.

Comment: Posted some codes. Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer below but the more I look at this, the more I think that you might want to review routing and templating in Angular.  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates and http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in other examples there are many ways to do this.  Direct DOM manipulation is not really the Angular way of thinking about this kind of use case.  A better way to think about it might be:

What possible content can this tab contain?
What will control its' being displayed?

Using the `ng-if` or `ng-switch` directive allows you to selectively limit the content based on a variable defined in the scope.

Consider this possibility:

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'tab1'}"><a ng-click="activeTab = 'tab1'" href="">tab1</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'tab2'}"><a ng-click="activeTab = 'tab2'" href="">tab2</a></li>
    <li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'tab3'}"><a ng-click="activeTab = 'tab3'" href="">tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Based on your code for the included file you could do this:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div ng-if="content==='A'" ng-include="'/'+activeTabA"></div>
  <div ng-if="content==='B'" ng-include="'/'+activeTabB"></div>
</div>
```

Another approach is to utilize ng-view and routing.  It is more complicated than conditionally including but less complicated than writing a whole new directive.

In short, you define a container element with the ng-view attribute like this

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Then set up a routing table in your javascript code like this

```
$routeProvider.when('/tab1', {templateUrl: 'partials/tab1.html', controller: 'tab1Controller'});
$routeProvider.when('/tab2', {templateUrl: 'partials/tab2.html', controller: 'tab2Controller'});
```

For more detail see this link: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive:ngView

Comment: `ng-if` is not a part of _stable_ angular (1.0.8) yet. It is available from 1.2 onwards.

Comment: As musically pointed out this angular 1.2 and not included in 1.08.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a fairly common AngularJS issue, and is handled pretty nicely by nested directives. It works well enough that it's actually one of the demos in the [Custom Directive Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) on the AngularJS docs page. It's the last example, "Creating Directives that Communicate". You can see the full code there, but the idea is that you create a 'container' directive for the tab group and a 'pane' directive for the inside content. Your HTML ends up looking like this:

```
<my-tabs>
  <my-pane title="Hello">
    <h5 id="pane1">Hello</h5>
    <p>This content is in the first pane.</p>
  </my-pane>
  <my-pane title="World">
    <h5 id="pane2">World</h5>
    <em>This content is in the second pane.</em>
  </my-pane>
</my-tabs>
```

As @musically_ut pointed out in his comment, there are a lot of ways to handle this. This is just one way, but I think it works out pretty well.

Comment: My question is: what if there is a link to xyz.html in one of the tabs  say tab1 and by clicking on this link you want to replace the tab1 content with xyz.html content?